# Azure/Microsoft Identity Platform - Cannot Retrieve Access Token from Token Endpoint (PHP)

Tags: php, azure, post, oauth, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to write a custom web app that utilizes the Microsoft Identity Platform to authenticate and authorize users. I'm able to successfully authenticate when calling the /authorize endpoint, and I have access to the "code" token that is returned.

I am now trying to retrieve my access token so that I can make calls to the APIs. Whenever I submit a POST request to the /token endpoint, the server returns a 400 Bad Request error. The header information that is provided contains no valuable information for troubleshooting and there is no JSON response returned so I have no idea where or what the issue is.

I'm making my call as follows:

```
$clientId = '00000000-0000-0000....'; // Omitted
$tenantId = '00000000-0000-0000....'; // Omitted
$grantType = 'authorization_code';
$scope = urlencode('User.Read');
$code = '......' // Obtained from authentication
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/smp/auth/handle';
$clientSecret = '...' // Omitted, set up in Azure App registrations under Certificates and secrets
$resource = 'api://00000000-0000-0000....'; // Omitted, set up in Azure App registrations under Overview -> App ID URI

$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$parameters = [
     'client_id' => $clientId,
     'grant_type' => $grantType,
     'scope' => $scope,
     'code' => $code,
     'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
     'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
     'resource' => $resource
];

$options = [
     'http' => [
          'method' => 'POST',
          'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => http_build_query($parameters)
     ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if (!$result) {
     exit('an error has occured');
}
```

PHP returns a warning that reads the following: (tenant id has been omitted):

**Warning**: file_get_contents(https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/oauth2/v2.0/token): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in **C:\xampp\htdocs\smp\application\models\user-model.php** on line **261**

I've verified everything I can possibly think of.

- The client and tenant ids are working (based on the successful authentication request).
- The "code" is correctly retrieved from the authentication request.
- Redirect Uri is the same as the one used for the authentication request.
- I've tried with and without the client_secret variable. It is my understanding that this is actually required in my case.
- I've tried with and without the resource variable, which is setup using the default Azure naming convention of "api://".

Please assist! I know I must be missing something but cannot figure it out. Perhaps permissions or additional setup within Azure? I'm not really sure what's wrong with my code/approach but Microsoft Identity Platform/OAuth isn't returning anything for me to work with and/or troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.

Firstly, I modified by `$options` variable to include the following:

```
$options = [
     'http' => [
          'method' => 'POST',
          'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => http_build_query($parameters),
          'ignore_errors' => true
     ]
];
```

Adding ignore_errors allowed me to see the returned JSON.

Next, it became apparent that my parameters were not being accepted because I was url-encoding all of them. My client secret, redirect uri, and client ids were all url encoded (this detail was hidden in my original post because it was just a small snippet of a much larger system). By undoing this encoding, my parameters all ended up being accepted. I suppose it makes sense because these values weren't being appended to a url but rather passed as POST values.

Lastly, the "resource" variable was not accepted (indeed, it wasn't required). Not sure if any of this is going to help anyone else but just in case, this was my fix.